# Django : HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm wondering why this error display and I've been using Postgresql and I have been observed this error occurs when I use IntegerField on my models like this one `b2_sacnumber_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)` or even using Integer field in local database. Is there any solution to get the value even I used IntergerFiled in my models? Im new in postgres , Can anyone explain to me about this it really helps me a lot.

*Error*

```
LINE 1: ...sac_forms" WHERE "b2_sac_forms"."b2_sacnumber_id" IN (31718,...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

*query views.py*

```
sample = ['31718','47060']
Sac_forms = list(B2SacForms.objects.using('matchy_data').values_list('b2_id', flat=True).filter(b2_sacnumber_id__in=sample))
```

*What I tried* changing the value `sample` like this one `sample = ['31718','47060']` or `sample = ["31718","47060"]`   and even I tried `sample = [31718,47060]` but still the error occurs

*models.py*

```
class B2SacForms(models.Model):
  b2_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  b2_sacnumber_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  generated_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'b2_sac_forms'
```

Comment: show the entire `B2SacForms.objects.using('matchy_data').values_list('b2_id', flat=True).filter(b2_sacnumber_id__in=sample).query`

Comment: @Tom Wojcik thanks for your response this what it looks like when prints `SELECT `b2_sac_forms`.`b2_id` FROM `b2_sac_forms` WHERE `b2_sac_forms`.`b2_sacnumber_id` IN (31718, 47060)`  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhk6k.png]

Comment: Check type of your database field, ensure that you properly migrated it to integer

Comment: @iklinac thanks for your response I've added my models above under `B2SacForms ` and I've also get the models using `inspectdb` in my command to get the database and I think it  ensurely migrated to integer, that's why I'm being confused in postgres